# Can offset x but not y when converting image

Tags: imagemagick-convert

Here's the overview of the problem. I want to crop an image to get a rectangle that is down a little and to the right a little. Somehow I can only set the x coordinate of the upper-left of the image. I can't get it to set the y coordinate of that rectangle - the upper part is always at the top.

Here's what the original image looks like. I can't post the actual original image because it's too large to upload.  You can download [the original image here](https://folio.unotate.com/folios/first/golden-retriever/244/med).

[image: original]

Here's the command I use to convert to a subset of that image:

```
/usr/bin/convert ./med.jpeg -crop 30%x12+300x50 ./ul.jpg
```

Which produces this image:

[image: result]

As you can see, it does a good job of offsetting the x axis, but it won't offset the y axis. The rectangle always starts at the top of the original image, no matter value I set at the end of the crop geometry.

So what am I missing here?

Here's the version of convert:

```
# convert -version
Version: ImageMagick 6.9.10-23 Q16 x86_64 20190101 https://imagemagick.org
Copyright: © 1999-2019 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: https://imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Features: Cipher DPC Modules OpenMP 
Delegates (built-in): bzlib djvu fftw fontconfig freetype jbig jng jpeg lcms lqr ltdl lzma openexr pangocairo png tiff webp wmf x xml zlib
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a simple typo in your ImageMagick command. You have put x in place of + between the X and Y offsets. Both must have either + or - not x.

You have

```
30%x12+300x50
```

and it should be

```
30%x12+300+50
```